# Como puedo hacer que las variables que tengo en una carpeta me sirvan en otra

Tags: php, html, mysqli

tengo un simple log in hecho todo en una carpeta en mi directorio, tengo la variable .name, que es el nombre del usuario registrado, en la carpeta donde esta todo el codigo sale bien, el nombre y todo pero cuando lo pongo en otro documento .php me sale este error. Undefined variable: _SESSION in......
Tiene toda la razón, pero como puedo hacer yo que la variable que ya tengo descrita en esa carpeta, en otro documento en el mismo proyecto. Salga también. 
Un saludo.

```
Welcome: <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar las variables almacenadas antes tienes que iniciar la sesión, escribiendo al principio de cada archivo .php la siguiente función:

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede comparar la sesión PHP con la cookie, pero la sesión es la forma mucho más segura de almacenar información. Las cookies almacenan datos en la computadora del usuario, pero las sesiones se almacenan en el servidor en un archivo temporal de forma segura

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["name"] = "John";
?
```

A continuación se muestra el ejemplo de recuperación de los datos de la sesión:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["name"];
?>
```

La variable global:session_start(); debe estar como primera linea en los documentos php donde deseas usarla. Un articulo si deseas conocer más del tema: https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-start-a-php-session-store-and-accessing-session-data/